# Virtualized collections item container consistency

Tags: c#, wpf, virtualization

I'm implementing a custom `MultiSelectionTreeView`. This control inherits from `ItemsControl`, `MultiSelectionTreeViewItem` inherits from `TreeViewItem`. 
Because of huge data set I want to bound to this control I use `VirtualizationStackPanel` as its host.

I bound the `TreeViewItems IsSelected` prop to the ViewModelClass `IsSelected` property.
When I scroll down in the tree, the selected items get out of the viewport, and the `IsSelected` properties are set to false (because of the virtualization the MultiSelectionTreeViewItems were disconnected from the Tree). When I scroll back a new item container(MultiSelectionTreeViewItem) is created and the IsSelected prop of that one is set to true according to the ViewModel.

Right now I can not decide if the Selected event occured because a container item went out from/came back to the viewport or there was change in the model or viewmodel layer.

What is worse I can not set the IsSelected properties of disconnected items. For example using Shift selection for more items with scrolling down.

I can't access the viewmodel class in my control implementation.

Any idea?

Comment: I would use snoop and check if the value was given as "local" or 
"binding" where a bound value is highlighted green.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom implementation of the virtualization, you could fix this problem. As it happens, I found a link to a book that I bought in a PDF online. This book has a great chapter on virtualisation (Chapter 8)... [WPF Control Development Unleashed](http://www.adorkable.us/books/wpf_control_development.pdf).

Although I have implemented my own virtualisation panels using this information, I would have to say that it is rather complicated. However, *if* you do implement your own system, you could add another property to your view model objects:

```
public bool IsRealized { get; set; }
```

'Realized' items are the items that are actually visible, as opposed to the 'virtualized' items that reside only in memory. So, with this property, you can adjust your `IsSelected` property to only react when the `IsRealized` property is `true`:

```
public bool IsSelected
{ 
    get { return isSelected; }
    set { if (IsRealized) { isSelected = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); }
}
```

Then in your custom virtualization panel, you can set the `IsRealized` property each time an item is realized or virtualized... I have to warn you though... it *will* be a lot of work.